# PHP MYSQL How to use Substring

Tags: php, mysql

I have this application where I want to display various albums from musicartists. My issue though is that the `track_duration`-field gives me for example `00:04:16` but what I want is `04:16` - so I tried to integrate the `MySQL SUBSTRING`-function but without luck.

My original `MySQL`-string looks like this:

```
SELECT products.title AS album_title, products.genre AS album_genre,
    products.ccws_pro_id AS product_upc, track_title, track_duration 
    FROM products
INNER JOIN track_albumn_information ON products.ccws_pro_upc = track_albumn_information.product_upc 
AND track_albumn_information.artist_id =  '".$artist_id."'  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

So, I tried to do `track_duration, SUBSTRING(track_duration, 3) FROM products...`

But that didnt work. It returned the same value `00:04:16`.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Define `didn't work`. Was there an error? Was the result other that the expected one? If yes, what?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I updated my question, it returned the same value..

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting both the original and the modified version.

Because you didn't give the substring version an alias, your PHP will be seeing a field that is literally called `SUBSTRING(track_duration, 3)`, plus the original as `track_duration`.

Looks like you just want the modified version, which can be done by giving it an alias:

```
SELECT products.title AS album_title, products.genre AS album_genre, products.ccws_pro_id AS product_upc, track_title, SUBSTRING(track_duration, 3) AS track_duration FROM products
```

Now in your PHP if you output the `track_duration` field for the rows, it will contain the modified data.

Comment: Hmm I use BackboneJS for my frontend, so I dont output the track_duration with `echo $track_duration`. The query returns the data as JSON, so somehow this does not work...

Answer (score 2):

You should check if there are realy leading zeros, otherwise you can do a "replace" by

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '00:' FROM '00:04:16');
```